# FPDF linebreak in PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

Hi so I am making a program that will fetch data from the database and display it in pdf. Some of my data are in paragraph. My problem is I have no idea how to put a linebreak in there. The output shows that they only took one line and all of the paragraphs are stack together. I am still new to this so I hope you guys can help me.

I watched some tutorial but hers were not from mysql so I'm still lost.

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

mysql_select_db('storm');

$sql="SELECT * FROM twothree";

$records=mysql_query($sql);

require("library/fpdf.php");

$pdf = new FPDF('p', 'mm', 'legal');

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

$pdf->cell(30, 10, "SS Height", 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->cell(30, 10, "Provinces", 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->cell(40, 10, "Municipalities of:", 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->cell(50, 10, "Impacts", 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->cell(50, 10, "Advice", 1, 1, 'C'); 

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){
    $pdf->cell(30, 10, $row['ssh'], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->cell(30, 10, $row['provi'], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->cell(40, 10, $row['muni'], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->cell(50, 10, $row['impact'], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->cell(50, 10, $row['advice'], 1, 1, 'C');
}


$pdf->OutPut();
?>
```

[Here's the pdf file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cIAU.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell is not compatible when you want to display paragraph. You can try check below link

[http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php ]

try to copy all the functions SetWidths, SetAligns, Row, CheckPageBreak, NbLines add to fpdf.php file

you could try like below use ROW

```
        $pdf->SetBorders(array('LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'TLR'));
        $pdf->SetWidths(array(30, 30, 40, 50, 50));
        $pdf->SetAligns(array('C', 'C', 'C', 'c', 'C'));

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
        $pdf->Row(array("SS Height",
                "Provinces",
                "Municipalities of:",
                "Impacts",
                "Advice"), 1);

        $pdf->SetBorders(array('L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'LR'));
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

            $pdf->Row(array($row['ssh'],
            $row['provi'],
            $row['muni'],
            $row['impact'],
            $row['advice']), 1);
        }
        $pdf->SetBorders(array('T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'));
        $pdf->Row(array('','','','',''), 1, false, 1);
```

in FPDF.PHP file added below functions

```
var $widths;
var $aligns;
var $borders;

function SetWidths($w)
{
    //Set the array of column widths
    $this->widths=$w;
}

function SetAligns($a)
{
    //Set the array of column alignments
    $this->aligns=$a;
}

function SetBorders($b)
{
    //Set the array of column borders
    $this->borders=$b;
}

function Row($data, $bdr=0, $fill=false, $hei=5)
{
    //Calculate the height of the row
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=$hei*$nb;
    //Issue a page break first if needed
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    //Draw the cells of the row
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        $b=isset($this->borders[$i]) ? $this->borders[$i] : 0;
        //Save the current position
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        if ($bdr == 1) {
            //Draw the border
            //$this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h, $sty);

            if(strpos($b,'L')!==false) 
                $this->Line($x, $y, $x, $y+$h);

            if(strpos($b,'R')!==false) 
                $this->Line($x+$w, $y, $x+$w, $y+$h);

            if(strpos($b,'T')!==false) 
                $this->Line($x, $y, $x+$w, $y);

            if(strpos($b,'B')!==false) 
                $this->Line($x, $y+$h, $x+$w, $y+$h);

        }
        //Print the text
        $this->MultiCell($w, $hei, $data[$i], $b, $a, $fill);
        //Put the position to the right of the cell
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    //Go to the next line
    $this->Ln($h);
}

function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    //If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}

function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
    //Computes the number of lines a MultiCell of width w will take
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}
```

Comment: The link is not working however I tried your given code but I got an error saying, "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF::SetBorders()"

Comment: in the link at end (]) bracket. try this http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php

Comment: I tried to follow that last night and got a little bit confused. What do you think is wrong with SetBorders(). They always give me that undefined method.

Answer (score 0):

Check out fpdf's built in http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm which is really just a wrapper, splitting up to multiple cell-calls.